# Trouble with Description naming GITHUB

Tags: github, git-bash

Hi i new to Git bash and currently i had some difficulties it seem i can't change the description of the File on the git hub i think on the git bash i click on
`git commit -m 'initial commit'` and now the description say's Initial commit as the description here i upload an image of it the Yellow highlight how do i change it ? the Yellow highlight how do i change it ? i try to search it on google but it gave me nothing.
[Yellow Highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq1QH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you write inside the `""` after the message argument `-m` is the description which will appear in the place.

You may change it to the desired string of your choice.
Eg : `git commit -m "<Your description>"`

Reference : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: i just closed my Gitbash and is there a way to continue where i left off ?

Comment: that's not needed, You can rather, run :
`git add .`,
`git commit -m "<your merssage>"`,
`git push origin <your-branch>`

Comment: when i follow the 2nd step of git commit -m it say's "On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean "

Comment: there are no changes, thus it gives out that message. Try making any changes and then running the commands

Comment: i dont understand  what does it mean make any changes ? im sorry im new to this

Comment: Make any changes to any file inside you local copy of the remote repo. then run the commands.

Comment: i think im starting to understanding and fix it already it seem what you mean is adding a file and commit another message.

Comment: please refer the guide I posted in my answer, It can help you understand and use git efficiently.